# Как по API обратиться к оборудованию сканера Atol Smart Slimp Plus?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть сканер штрих кодов Atol Smart Slimp Plus как на фотографии ниже

[image: Сканер штрих-кодов Atol Smart Slimp Plus]

На этой же фотографии запущена демонстрационная программа которая считывает штрих-коды. По умолчанию это единственная программа с которой работает сканер. Другие программы, которые уже интегрируются с 1c и с которыми уже как то можно работать платные.

Рассматривается вариант написания собственного приложения для Android в котором бы мы могли реализовать нужный нам функционал, весь вопрос к том как в Android Studio обратиться к оборудованию сканера, то есть активировать его и получить с него данные в переменную или в буфер. Можете ли привести пример кода по работе с API сканера?

Если кто то хорошо разбирается в Android при этом не знаком с оборудованием сканера готов попробовать разобраться, рассматривается вариант платного поиска решения, то есть рассматривается вариант предоставить Вам какие либо варианты удалённого доступа к ПК к которому подключён сканер. Предлагайте стоимость.(P.S. разработка интерфейса будущей программы в настоящее время не требуется, хотя и могут быть различные варианты и такого сотрудничества в перспективе, то есть сейчас нужно понимание как из своих приложений Android получить доступ к оборудованию сканера).

В Атол письмо написали с просьбой предоставить информацию по доступу к оборудованию сканера из приложения. Ответа пока нет. Информации по этому поводу в Интернет не нашёл, только куча сайтов с предложениями купить сканер.

Comment: Andrew, поясните пожалуйста с чём связан Ваш голос за закрытие вопроса? Попробуйте найти информацию по вопросу в Интернет...

Comment: Android Studio это среда разработки, она к оборудованию не обращается. То что сканер подключен к ПК, никак не влияет на возможность работы с ним с мобильного устройства. Правильно, что обратились к производителю, только оттуда и надо черпать информацию. А обьявления о работе на SO неуместны, поэтому я тоже голосую за закрытие.

Comment: Вы пишите "Android Studio ... к оборудованию не обращается". Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли какое то принципиальное отличие при работе из студии с камерой и указанным сканером штрихкодов. Почему не обращается? Тогда что происходит при работы с камерой? Это не обращение к оборудованию что-ли?

Comment: Ваше приложение будет запускаться где? И что ему нужно для запуска уже готового приложения? Только Андроид-устройство. Вот оно к оборудованию и обращается. Приложения можно писать хоть в Блокноте, но это же не будет означать что Блокнот обращается к камере. Он и понятия не имеет что она существует. Не путайте среду разработки со средой исполнения.

Comment: Так в задании указано, что интересует информация как из андроид приложения которое будет установлено в сканер под android работать с оборудованием сканера. Не имелось ввиду получить доступ с ПК к сканеру. Информация про ПК приведена с целью донести до потенциального исполнителя(или пользователя который изъявит желание попробовать разобраться), что мы предоставим удалённый доступ к ПК на котором стоит Android Strudio и к которому подключён сканер для старта на нём приложений из студии. Это написано поскольку не у Всех же есть такой сканер и может быть просто не на чем тестировать.